# The Arithmetic Derivative

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, arithmetic, number-theory

The derivative of a function is a cornerstone of mathematics, engineering, physics, biology, chemistry, and a large number of other sciences as well. Today we're going to be calculating something only tangentially related: the arithmetic derivative.

## Definition

The arithmetic derivative `a(n)` or `n'` is defined here ([A003415](http://oeis.org/A003415)) by a number of properties that are similar to the derivative of a function.

- `a(0) = a(1) = 0`,
- `a(p) = 1`, where `p` is any prime, and
- `a(mn) = m*a(n) + n*a(m)`.

The third rule is based on the product rule for differentiation of functions: for functions `f(x)` and `g(x)`, `(fg)' = f'g + fg'`. So with numbers, `(ab)' = a'b + ab'`.

Also of note, since the arithmetic derivative can be extended to the negative numbers via this simple relation, `a(-n) = -a(n)`, the input may be negative.

## Rules

- Write a program or function that, given any integer `n`, returns the arithmetic derivative of `n`.
- Inputs will be `-230 < n < 230`, to avoid problems with integer sizes and numbers too large to factor in a reasonable amount of time. Your algorithm should still be able to theoretically calculate the arithmetic derivative of numbers outside this range.
- Built-ins for symbolic math, prime factorization and differentiation are allowed.

## Examples

```
> a(1)
0
> a(7)
1
> a(14)   # a(7)*2 + a(2)*7 = 1*2 + 1*7 = 9
9
> a(-5)   # a(-5) = -a(5) = -1
-1
> a(8)    # a(8) = a(2**3) = 3*2**2 = 12
12
> a(225)  # a(225) = a(9)*25 + a(25)*9 = 6*25 + 10*9 = 150 + 90 = 240
240
> a(299792458)  # a(299792458) = a(2)*149896229 + a(7)*42827494 + a(73)*4106746 + a(293339)*1022 = 1*149896229 + 1*42827494 + 1*4106746 + 1*1022 = 149896229 + 42827494 + 4106746 + 1022 = 196831491
196831491
```

As always, if the problem is unclear, please let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

Comment: What, exactly, is `prime` in `a(prime)`?  Is it just a prime number?

Comment: Also, I don't get how you decomposed the last example.

Comment: @Stackstuck Yes, it's any prime. I've edited for clarity. Also, I added to the last example to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 12 bytes

```
|1>?GtYf/s}0
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=fDE-P0d0WWYvc30w&input=Mjk5NzkyNDU4)

#### Explanation

Consider an integer *a* with |*a*|>1, and let the (possibly repeated) prime factors of |*a*| be *f*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *f*<sub>*n*</sub>. Then the desired result is *a*·(1/*f*<sub>1</sub> + ... + 1/*f*<sub>*n*</sub>).

```
|1>     % take input's absolute value. Is it greater than 1?
?       % if so:
  Gt    %   push input twice
  Yf    %   prime factors. For negative input uses its absolute value
  /     %   divide element-wise
  s     %   sum of the array
}       % else:
  0     %   push 0
```

Comment: Isn't the sum of the prime factors of 1 equal to 0? Or doesn't that work in MATL?

Comment: @wythagoras Actually `1` gives `1` as its "prime" number decomposition. It's a strange result (an empty array would be more meaningful). But that's how Matlab works. And also CJam. So I guess there must be good reason to output `1` in that case? What do you think? I've been tempted to redefine the `Yf` function to output an empty array for `1`, but I wasn't sure

Comment: Pyth gives an empty array, fwiw.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! Maybe I'll change that

Comment: Same in Mathematica (was almost a problem once)

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 59 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,p=2:+(n*n>1)and(n%p and f(n,p+1)or p*f(n/p)+n/p)
```

A recursive function. On large inputs, it runs out of stack depth on typical systems unless you run it with something like [Stackless Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackless_Python).

The recursive definition is implemented directly, counting up to search for candidate prime factors. Since `f(prime)=1`, if `n` has a prime `p` as a factor, we have `f(n) == p*f(n/p)+n/p`.

Comment: Don't you need input and print? At least when I run this (Python 2), I get no result.

Comment: @wythagoras By default, [functions are allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419/20260) as an alternative to programs. Also, this challenge says "program or function".

Answer (score 8):

## Jelly, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*-1 byte by @Dennis*

```
ÆfḟṠ³:S
```

Uses the same formula everyone else does. However, there's a little trick to deal with `0`.

```
o¬AÆfİS×     Main link. Inputs: n
o¬             Logical OR of n with its logical NOT
               That is, 0 goes to 1 and everything else goes to itself.
  A            Then take the absolute value
   Æf          get its list of prime factors
     İ         divide 1 by those
      S        sum
       ×       and multiply by the input.
```

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4Zm4bif4bmgwrM6Uw&input=&args=LTI5OTc5MjQ1OA).

Comment: Can you please add an explanation? I like answers to have explanations before I upvote them.

Comment: @Sherlock9 Done.

Comment: I see that your answer has been golfed and the explanation is now out-of-date. Would you please fix that? Thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, <s>87</s> <s>78</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```python
a=b=input()
d=2
s=0
while d<=abs(b):
    if a%d==0:
        a=a/d
        s+=b/d
    else:
        d+=1
print s
```

Improvements thanks to @Maltysen:

```python
a=b=input()
d=2
s=0
while d<=abs(b):
    if a%d==0:a/=d;s+=b/d
    else:d+=1
print s
```

Further improvement by two bytes:

```python
a=b=input()
d=2
s=0
while abs(a)>1:
    if a%d<1:a/=d;s+=b/d
    else:d+=1
print s
```

Further improvement thanks to @xnor:

```python
a=b=input()
d=2
s=0
while a*a>1:
    if a%d<1:a/=d;s+=b/d
    else:d+=1
print s
```

#### Explanation

The arithmetic derivative of `a` is equal to `a` times the sum of the reciprocals of the prime factors of `a`. No exception for 1 is needed since the sum of the reciprocals of the prime factors of 1 is zero.

Comment: `abs(a)>1` can be `a*a>1`.

Comment: @xnor Yes, thank you.

Comment: Replace line 2 with `d,s = 2,0`

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Both are 8 bytes in total.

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>30</s> <s>27</s> 19 chars

Thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for chopping off 3 characters.

Thanks to [@Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014/zgarb) for chopping off 8 characters.

```
0:`(*[:+/%@q:@|)@.*
```

[Try it online!](http://tryj.tk/)

Sample input:

```
0:`(*[:+/%@q:@|)@.* _8
_12

0:`(*[:+/%@q:@|)@.* 0
0

0:`(*[:+/%@q:@|)@.* 8
12
```

How it works:

```
0:`(*[:+/%@q:@|)@.* N
XX`YYYYYYYYYYYYY@.Z   if Z then Y else X end
0:                        X:  return 0
                  Z       Z:  signum(N)
   (*[:+/%@q:@|)          Y:  N*add_all(reciprocal_all(all_prime_factors(abs(N))))
                              N
    *                          *
      [:+/                      add_all(                                         )
          %@                            reciprocal_all(                         )
            q:@                                       all_prime_factors(      )
               |                                                        abs( )
                                                                            N
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>203</s> 90 bytes

Thanks @nimi!

I still have no idea when what indentations cause what interpretation, this is the shortest I managed so far, and as always, I'm sure it can be golfed a lot more. I'm going to try again in the evening.

```
n#(x:_)|y<-div n x=x*a y+y*a x;_#_=1
a n|n<0= -a(-n)|n<2=0|1<2=n#[i|i<-[2..n-1],mod n i<1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, teacher=)  I can always learn so much whenever you help me out here! Feel free to add your version as your own answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Lovin' the implicit input! Should bring it on par with Jelly for most things (Except Dennis' golfing skills).

```
*scL1P.a
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2ascL1P.a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A7%0A14%0A-5%0A8%0A225%0A299792458&debug=0).

```
*             Times the input, implicitly (This also adds the sign back in)
 s            Sum
  cL1         Reciprocal mapped over lit
   P          Prime factorization
    .a        Absolute value of input, implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 59 bytes

```haskell
n%p|n*n<2=0|mod n p>0=n%(p+1)|r<-div n p=r+p*r%2
(%2)
```

Implements the recursive definition directly, with an auxiliary variable `p` that counts up to search for potential prime factors, starting from `2`. The last line is the main function, which plugs `p=2` to the binary function defined in the first line.

The function checks each case in turn:

- If `n*n<2`, then `n` is one of `-1,0,1`, and the result is `0`.
- If `n` is not a multiple of `p`, then increment `p` and continue.
- Otherwise, express `n=p*r`, and by the "derivative" property, the result is `r*a(p)+p*a(r)`, which simplifies to `r+p*a(r)` because `p` is prime.

The last case saves bytes by [binding `r` in a guard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76749/20260), which also avoids the `1>0` for the boilerplate `otherwise`. If `r` could be bound earlier, the second condition `mod n p>0` could be checked as `r*p==n`, which is 3 bytes shorter, but I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>13</s> 9 bytes

A simple solution. The Dyalog Unicode version was simply a longer version of this so it has been omitted.

**Edit:** Saved 4 bytes by adopting the method in [lirtosiast's Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76976/47581).

```apl
{+/⍵÷⍭|⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v1pb/1Hv1sPbD29/1DHjUeeiRz07HvWurQGK1f5Pe9Q24VFv36O@qZ7@j7qaD603ftQ2EcgLDnIGkiEensH/0w6tMFQwVzA0UTi03lTBQsHIyBQA)

**Ungolfing**

```apl
{+/⍵÷⍭|⍵}

{        }  A dfn, a function in {} brackets.
     ⍭|⍵   The prime factors of the absolute value of our input.
   ⍵÷      Then divide our input by the above array,
            giving us a list of products for the product rule.
 +/         We sum the above numbers, giving us our arithmetic derivative.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [-x](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339), <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
ÒU©a k £/X
```

*- 6 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///Ck0EMrExWyFQ4t1o/4/9/QREG3AgA)

Comment: Both fail for negative numbers because, for some reason, `N.k()` doesn't work on them.

Comment: [Here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YSDJqVVhIGsgoy9Yw3g=&input=WzEsNywxNCwtNSw4LDIyNV0KLW0=)'s a fix, with some golfing.

Comment: Or [-2 more byes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YSDJqVVhIGsgoy9Y&input=LTUKLXg=) with the `-x` flag.

Comment: [Knocked another byte off](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ssmpVWEgayCjL1jDeA==&input=WzAsMSw3LDE0LC01LDgsMjI1LDI5OTc5MjQ1OF0KLW0=)

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, nice

Comment: [11 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=0lWpYSBrIHhAL1g=&input=WzAsMSw3LDE0LC01LDgsMjI1LDI5OTc5MjQ1OF0KLW0=)

Comment: (Or [10, with `-x`](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=0lWpYSBrIKMvWA==&input=LTUKLXg=))

Comment: @Shaggy Ah, nice, still learning! :) Forgot about flags and the fact that summing can take a function, as with many other functions in japt

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>87</s> <s>66</s> <s>80</s> <s>75</s> <s>70</s> 68 bytes

This answer is based on [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76949/47581), [wythagoras's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76957/47581), and the idea that the arithmetic derivative of a number `m` is equal to `m·(1/p1 + 1/p2 + ... + 1/pn)` where `p1...pn` is every prime factor of `n` to multiplicity.

```ruby
->n{s=0;(2...m=n.abs).map{|d|(m/=d;s+=n/d)while m%d<1};m<2?0:s+0**s}
```

This function is called in the following way:

```ruby
> a=->n{s=0;(2...m=n.abs).map{|d|(m/=d;s+=n/d)while m%d<1};m<2?0:s+0**s}
> a[299792458]
196831491
```

**Ungolfing:**

```ruby
def a(n)
  s = 0
  m = n.abs
  (2...m).each do |z|
    while m%d == 0
      m /= d
      s += n / d
    end
  end
  if s == 0
    if n > 1
      s += 1 # if s is 0, either n is prime and the while loop added nothing, so add 1
             # or n.abs < 2, so return 0 anyway
             # 0**s is used in the code because it returns 1 if s == 0 and 0 for all other s
    end
  end
  return s
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>72</s> 43 bytes

```
n->n^2>1?sum(p->n÷/(p...),factor(n^2))/2:0
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns a float. To call it, assign it to a variable.

For an input integer *n*, if *n*<sup>2</sup> ≤ 1 return 0. Otherwise obtain the prime factorization of *n*<sup>2</sup> as a `Dict`, then for each prime/exponent pair, divide the prime by its exponent, then divide *n* by the result. This is just computing *n* *x* / *p*, where *p* is the prime factor and *x* is its exponent, which is the same as summing *n* / *p*, *x* times. We sum the resulting array and divide that by 2, since we've summed twice as much as we need. That's due to the fact that we're factoring *n*<sup>2</sup> rather than *n*. (Doing that is a byte shorter than factoring |*n*|.)

Saved 29 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 2):

## [Seriously](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>17</s> <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 12 bytes

My first ever Seriously answer. This answer is based on [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76949/47581) and the idea that the arithmetic derivative of a number `m` is equal to `m·(1/p1 + 1/p2 + ... + 1/pn)` where `p1...pn` is every prime factor of `n` to multiplicity. My addition is to note that, if `m = p1e1·p2e2·...·pnen`, then `a(m) = m·(e1/p1 + e2/p2 + ... + en/pn)`. Thanks to [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego) for golfing and bug fixing help. [Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LDt3YGlAL2BNzqMqbA&input=LTEy)

```
,;w`i@/`MΣ*l
```

**Ungolfing:**

```
,             get a single input
 ;w           duplicate input and get prime factorization, p_f
               for input [-1..1], this returns [] and is dealt with at the end
   `   `M     map the function inside `` to p_f
    i         pop all elements of p_f[i], the prime and the exponent, to the stack
     @        rotate so that the exponent is at the top of the stack
      /       divide the exponent by the prime
         Σ    sum it all together
          *   multiply this sum with the input
           l  map and multiply do not affect an empty list, so we just take the length, 0
               l is a no-op for a number, so the result is unchanged for all other inputs
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 10.0, 39 bytes

```
Tr[If[#>1,#2/#,0]&@@@FactorInteger@#]#&
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation? I like answers to have explanations before I upvote them.

Comment: @Sherlock9 This is a quite uninteresting answer so I don't plan to add one. It's OK if no one upvotes it.

Comment: Alright, then. Have a good day :)

Comment: In the current Mathematica version, `FactorInteger@1` yields `{1,1}`, so the `If` function is no longer necessary, saving 10 bytes.

Comment: @GregMartin Seriously? That's even more inconsistent than the value, `{{1,1}}`, returned by my version (`{}` is the expected result to me).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `{{1,1}}`. Mathematically `{}` makes more sense, of course ... but I admit that `{{1,1}}` makes coding a little easier. And `FactorInteger[-1]` returns `{{-1,1}}` (maybe that's not a change).

Comment: @GregMartin I don't understand how an inconsistent behavior would make coding easier... anyway, `{{1,1}}` is not a different result than when I wrote this answer, so the `If` must be there for a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 13 bytes

```
*jmauΜm)jd/1H
```

Kudos to the MATL answer for the algorithm! [Try it here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=KmptYXXOnG0pamQvMUg), [or test them all at once](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=b25bMSwgNywgMTQsIC01LCA4LCAyMjUsIDI5OTc5MjQ1OF0KzpxuZM26SCpIbWF1zpxtKUhkLzFI). (Outputs [key,out] in an array.)

### Explanation

```
*jmauΜm)jd/1H
*j             input times
      m)j         p.f. of input
     Μ   d/1H      mapped to inverse
    u            sum of
  ma            abs of
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 35 char, 70 bytes

```
{1≥a←∣⍵:0⋄1=≢k←πa:×⍵⋄c+m×∇c←⍵÷m←↑k}
```

test and how to use:

```
  f←{1≥a←∣⍵:0⋄1=≢k←πa:×⍵⋄c+m×∇c←⍵÷m←↑k}
  f 14
9
  f 8
12
  f 225
240
  f ¯5
¯1
  f 299792458
196831491
```

I thought that it would not be ok because I don't know if c variable is composed (and not a prime)... But seems ok for the test...

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÄÒ÷O
```

Port of [*@lirtosiast*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76976/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cMvhSYe3@///r2tkaWluaWRiagEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCf8PtxyedHi7/3@d/9EGOoY65jqGJjq6pjoWOkZGpjpGlpbmlkYmphY6unBmLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ä     # Take the absolute value of the (implicit) input
 Ò    # Get all its prime factors (with duplicates)
  ÷   # Integer divide the (implicit) input by each of these prime factors
   O  # And take the sum (which is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 44 bytes

```
n->n*vecsum([i[2]/p|i<-factor(n)~,0<p=i[1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzRCsIgGEZf5WNXGr@UsrEJ215EvJCRIZT92AqC6NXNrr5z4PBxKElduEYsqFmt@fA6b4/nTbjkjD/yJ80qhm2/F5Hll04zL8lp72UNzNe3yFAruKS8N@z@0iG2VBKcJowE3RPUQJgIxrQ11o7W9MPUPn4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 3 bytes

```
ȧǐ/
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C8%A7%C7%90%2F&inputs=225&header=&footer=)

```
ȧ   # Abs. val
 ǐ  # All prime factors
    # (Implicit input)
  / # Divided by each factor.  
    # (s flag) sum of stack
```

-1 thx to Underslash

Comment: [3 bytes -s](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C8%A7%C7%90%2F&inputs=225&header=&footer=) If you remove the -r flag, you can get implicit input for the dividing.

Comment: @Underslash Thx!

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 62 bytes

```
perl -MMath::Prime::Util=:all -E"map$i+=1/$_,factor abs($j=<>);say$i*$j"
```

Uses the formula (from OEIS): `If n = Product p_i^e_i, a(n) = n * Sum (e_i/p_i).`

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 6, 90

```
sub A(\n) {0>n??-A(-n)!!(n>1)*{$_??n/$_*A($_)+$_*A n/$_!!1}(first n%%*,2..^n)};say A slurp
```

This might be a bit slow for large numbers. Replace `2..^n` with `2..n.sqrt` for longer code but faster computation.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 183 bytes

```
==function a(n)
{n<0:
~return-a(-n)
}
{n<2:
~return 0
}
~temp f=t(n,2)
{f:
~return a(n/f)*f+n/f
}
~return 1
==function t(n,i)
{n>1&&n-i:
{n%i:
~return t(n,i+1)
}
~return i
}
~return 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoMgEEX3nIJNDdSSAtFYTOldTCMJaTo2BldGr06HYqqrN7zh//HwinPHFF8IoslQVaaoM28ZWm9vbUxjdFWjj9a6CZ7BD0A7BpzMcJctWcc@TCMI7EC3JKv/lko0a@jfH@psYHDRGHP7Gnuujp9diUg/N63I4VaK@XTtoYoChG9xPPm947cvFT/k/WGWMX4B)

I refuse to believe this is a good solution, but I can't see a way to improve it either.